# NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException - Spring DI with Strategy Pattern

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, annotations, strategy-pattern

I am trying to implement a communication Service functionality based on Strategy Pattern using Spring. I have the following classes -

**Interface** - **MessageService.java**

```
package com.xxx

public Interface MessageService{

    String sendMessage(String idOrNumber);

}
```

**Implementation Classes -**

**1) EmailService.java**

```
package com.xxx

@Component
public class EmailService implements MessageService{

        public String sendMessage(String idOrNumber){

    // Do some operation

    return "success"

    } 

}
```

**2) SmsService.java**

```
package com.xxx

@Component
public class SmsService implements MessageService{

        public String sendMessage(String idOrNumber){

    // Do some operation

    return "success"

    } 

}
```

**CommunicationFactory Class**

```
package com.xxx

@Component
public class CommunicationFactory {

    @Resource(name ="smsService")
    private SmsService smsService 


    @Resource(name ="emailService")
    private EmailService emailService;


    public MessageService getCommunicationChannel(String channel){

    MessageService messageService = null;

    if("sms".equals(channel){

    messageService = smsService;    

    }

    if("email".equals(channel){

    messageService = emailService;

    }

   return messageService;

}
```

I have a mail Service implementation class

```
package com.xxx

@Component
@Service
public class CommunicationServiceImpl implements CommunicationService {

      @Autowired
      private MessageService messageService;

      CommunicationFactory communicationFactory;


      @Override
      public String sendCommunication(String idOrNumber){

        //Which implementation be called - SMS or EMAIL
        messageService = communicationFactory.getCommunicationChannel(channel);

        String statusMessage = messageService.sendMessage(idOrNumber);

        }

}
```

I am getting the following error while running the server.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.xxx.MessageService com.xxx.CommunicationServiceImpl.messageService; nested exception is 

org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.xxx.MessageService] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: smsService,emailService
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514) [spring-beans-

3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285) [spring-beans-

3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.xxx.MessageService] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: 

smsService,emailService
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:863) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:768) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486) [spring-beans-

3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 27 more
```

Where I am going wrong? Any pointers would be helpful

Comment: You have no qualifier in the service class.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

Implementation Classes -

```
1) EmailService.java

package com.xxx

@Component("emailService")
public class EmailService implements MessageService{

        public String sendMessage(String idOrNumber){

    // Do some operation

    return "success"

    } 

}
2) SmsService.java

package com.xxx

@Component("smsService")
public class SmsService implements MessageService{

        public String sendMessage(String idOrNumber){

    // Do some operation

    return "success"

    } 

}
```

And the problem is here:

```
@Autowired
private MessageService messageService;
```

The possible solution is @Autowired both services.

```
@Autowired
private MessageService smsService;
@Autowired
private MessageService emailService;
```

or, if you have the same problem.

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("smsService")
private MessageService smsService;
@Autowired
@Qualifier("emailService")
private MessageService emailService;
```

Comment: Dani, I tried your suggestion. It didn't work either. I am getting the same exception

Comment: Ok, I think your problem is here @Autowired
      private MessageService messageService;, Cause when Spring DI try to inject that reference, are two beans with the same interface and Spring can't decide which one set. Define one or reimplement this approach.

Comment: I like helping people to get negative votes as present... Great attitude.

Comment: Before your edit, your answer was code without explanation that was wrong. Beans, by default, take their name from the simple name of their type. So a bean of type `SmsService` would be called `smsService` already. Explicitly giving it that name in the `@Component` annotation is just clearer, but changes nothing in this particular example. After your edit, your answer is still missing the main point, which you've posted as a comment. Edit that in, and maybe the person who downvoted you will change their mind.

Comment: I know all you're telling me, but I was helping, in a first look I didn't see the main question, but I wouldn't put a negative vote to another user which is helping to another until abandon the thread, when you help nobody give you a positive vote, but get the negatives is very quickly... I don't understand this attitude, it putting me off the desire to helping others.

Comment: Hi Dani, I tried your suggestions, none of them worked, but it gave me direction to look into. Really Appreciate your help. "SuperMan"s who blindly downvote the answer should put up a valid reason.

Comment: If any of both suggestions are not working, I only can thinking in specify the implementation classes directly in Autowired (but this shouldn't be needed at first... Cause the exception is very clear). 
private SmsServices msService;
private EmailService emailService;

Answer (score 0):

The simplest implementation i know is to rely on an injected list of services and having a get method to fetch the responsible service:

```
package com.xxx

@Component
public class CommunicationFactory {

    /**
     * This list would be ordered if the interface is implementing `org.springframework.core.Ordered` or an implementation declares `@org.springframework.core.annotation.Order`(in Spring 4)
     */
    @Autowired
    private List<MessageService> messageServices; 

    /**
     * @return the FIRST communication channel for the given channel
     */
    public MessageService getCommunicationChannel(String channel){
        for (MessageService ms : messageServices) {
            if (ms.supports(channel)) {
                return ms;
            }
        }
        return null; // or a default :)
    }

    /**
     * With this implementation you can even have multiple implementations firing a message if they support the given channel.
     * @return a list of communication channels that support the given channel
     */
    public List<MessageService> getCommunicationChannels(String channel){
        List<MessageService> supporting = new ArrayList<>();
        for (MessageService ms : messageServices) {
            if (ms.supports(channel)) {
                supporting.add(ms);
            }
        }
        return supporting;
    }
}
```